# Sh script to reduce version number in opkg status file

Tags: linux, sh, installer

I have written a script to reduce/lower the version number stored in opkg status file using small shell script, This will enable us to force the opkg to install same version of a Debian package again.

Versions stored in the opkg files are as follows,

```
Version: 00.03.00a002
Version: 2013.07.001
Version: 2013.07.001
Version: 3.12.002
```

And my script is as shown below, This script would run on the embedded board which is having busybox based `sh` shell. I have put bash tag to reach more people.

Script edits either 1st version number or 2nd version number..I didn't take third because sometimes that would contain alphanumeric value and I am uncomfortable with handling hex subtraction.

```
#!/bin/sh

#Small script to Lower firmware version 

OPKG_STATUS_FILE="/var/lib/opkg/status"
stamp=$(date +%s)
BACKUP_OPKG_STATUS_FILE="/var/lib/opkg/status_${stamp}"


#Creating backup file so that we can get back actual version if we want
cp ${OPKG_STATUS_FILE} ${BACKUP_OPKG_STATUS_FILE}
echo "${BACKUP_OPKG_STATUS_FILE} file created"

#clear original status file
:> ${OPKG_STATUS_FILE}

while IFS=' ' read -r line || [ -n "${line}" ];do
    ver_found=""
    ver_found=$(echo "${line}" | grep -i "Version")

    if [ ! -z "${ver_found}" ];then
        ver_extracted=""
        new_line=""
        for i in 1 2;do
            ver_extracted=$(echo "${line}" | grep -i "Version" | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d '.' -f ${i})
            if [ ! -z "${ver_extracted}" ];then
            {
                #reduce version number
                if [ "${ver_extracted}" -gt 0 ];then
                    new_version=$(printf "%02d %02d" "${ver_extracted}" "01" | awk '{ printf "%.0f", $1 - $2 }')
                    new_line=$(echo ${line} | sed -e "s:${ver_extracted}:${new_version}:I")
                    line="${new_line}"
                else
                    continue
                fi
                break
            }
            fi
        done
    fi
    echo "${line}" >> "${OPKG_STATUS_FILE}"
done < "${BACKUP_OPKG_STATUS_FILE}"
```

I wanted to ask

1. if there is a better method for doing this.
2. One problem what I observed with my script is `03` is reduced and replaced with `2` **instead** of `02`
   I need to keep versions digits same, any suggestion for that ?

Comment: The problem you describe sounds like a bug, which would make this off-topic for CR.

Comment: how about better/simpler method any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using `awk` in there,
it would be better to rewrite all the `echo` - `grep` - `sed` processing with a single `awk`.
In particular, the entire `while` loop in the middle can be replaced with this:

```
awk -F '[:. ]' '/^Version: / {
  num1 = $3;
  num2 = $4;
  if (num1 > 0) {
    gsub(num1, num1 - 1);
    print;
  } else if (num2 > 0) {
    gsub(num2, num2 - 1);
    print;
  }
}
' "${BACKUP_OPKG_STATUS_FILE}" >> "${OPKG_STATUS_FILE}"
```

This produces slightly different (I think better) output than your original,
and with the number of sub-processes greatly reduced,
it's a lot more efficient.

Comment: this doesn't work on busybox shell. :( `awk: cmd. line:2: Call to undefined function`

Comment: Hm, that's probably because of the `strtonum` function I used. I removed it, it's probably not really needed (not for your example data anyway)